# Assign variable to backup if first condition is nil - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set a variable with a value. But in some instances this value will not exist. In the scenario I want to set it to the Null Class I built. Here is what I'm working with:

`coupon = rsvp.purchases.map(&:coupon) || NullCoupon.new`

With this line I'm trying to say - `if rsvp.purchases.coupons is nil assign coupon to NullCoupon.new`. I'm clearly doing something wrong but how can I achieve this?

### Error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method "coupon" for #<Purchase::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fadb410a478>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I see now from the error that the problem isn't with your `||` operator, it's with your `rsvp.purchases.map(&:coupon)` method chaining. It's not finding a `coupon` for one of the purchases.

You can solve this by ensuring that purchases always have coupons with validations, or you can use the `.try` method from Rails.

[Try method in Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Object/try)

**Original**

In Ruby, `nil` and `false` are the only things that are not truthy. So,
coupon will be equal to `rsvp.purchases.map(&:coupon)` unless `rsvp.purchases.map(&:coupon)` is equal to `nil` or `false`.

Can you be more specific and give examples about the error(s) that you are receiving?

Examples Below:

```
irb(main):019:0> coupon = nil || 1
=> 1
irb(main):020:0> coupon = "" || 1
=> ""
irb(main):021:0> coupon = false || 1
=> 1
irb(main):022:0> coupon = 4 || 1
=> 4
irb(main):023:0> coupon = OpenStruct.new || 1
=> #<OpenStruct>
irb(main):024:0> coupon = false || OpenStruct.new
=> #<OpenStruct>
irb(main):025:0> coupon = nil || OpenStruct.new  
=> #<OpenStruct>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the first element of the coupons array, or nil if there are no elements.

(this assumes there's a many-to-one relationship between coupons and purchases)

```
coupon = rsvp.purchases.coupons.first || NullCoupon.new
```